# Example divide and conquer algorithm with recurrence T(n) = T(n/2) + O(n)

Tags: divide-and-conquer

I'm working on some lecture notes and wondered if there was a good example algorithm for the recurrence equation

$$T(n) = T(n/2) + n$$

I know that I can do selection in this running time, but that is a probabilistic algorithm, and I was hoping not to introduce this algorithm at this point in my lecture notes. I plan to introduce the selection problem in a later chapter after describing quick-sort. Is there a good example of an algorithm that has this recurrence equation as worst-case?

Comment: Quickselect only recurses on one branch so it would have recurrence T(n) = T(n/2) + n (assuming good choice of pivots).

Comment: Unfortunately, that is the algorithm I (explicitly) mentioned I wasn't interested in because it has a probabilistic running time. I have already planned to mention it in my lecture notes, but I would prefer to cover randomised analyses in the next chapter, and I would prefer to have all the recurrence equations I need in the same chapter. This is why I am interested in a non-probabilistic algorithm with this running time. I want to have the equation in a chapter before I cover randomisation, and I need the equation for the following chapter. :-/

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize what you meant by "selection".

Comment: No worries. Thanks anyway. It is also the only example I can think of :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using *binary sum*, i.e., adding the numbers in a list pairwise:

```
def binary_sum(x):
    if len(x) == 0: return 0
    if len(x) == 1: return x[0]

    # O(n) work
    y = []
    for i in range(1, len(x), 2):
        y.append(x[i - 1] + x[i])
    if i + 1 < len(x): # handle odd lengths
        y[0] += x[i + 1]

    return binary_sum(y) # recurse on n//2 size
```

I justify this with a story about numerical issues when adding numbers of very different orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 2):

Bottom-up heap construction. Choose one application of sift-down as your unit of measurement. Then the recurrence is $T(n) = T(n/2) + n$.

If you want to go beyond that, you can say that choosing sift-down as a unit for measurement isn't quite accurate, and its runtime depends on the height $h$ of heap being sifted down in. But you can show that bottom-up heap construction is still $O(n)$ due to

$$0\cdot n + 1\cdot \frac{n}{2} + 2\cdot \frac{n}{4} + \cdots + h\cdot 1 = \sum_{h=0}^{\lg n} h\frac{n}{2^h} < n\sum_{h=0}^\infty \frac{h}{2^h}$$

and showing (or simply stating without proof in case you feel the students are not ready yet) that $\sum_{h=0}^\infty \frac{h}{2^h}$ converges to a constant.

Comment: Thanks. That is a perfect example. It will also let me introduce help sort shortly after

Comment: Well, actually I do find it hard to put this into the right recursive form. Since sift-down is so obviously not constant, it is harder to explain that this is an example of the recurrence equation... since you need to get the running time from the convergent series, I cannot simply invoke the recurrence. :(

Comment: @ThomasMailund Take note of my first paragraph: _"Choose one application of sift-down as your unit of measurement."_ It is important your students are aware that there is always some unit of measurement chosen, and sometimes it is easier to analyze a problem by first choosing a unit of measurement that is not necessarily constant in a more precise unit of measurement.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. And you are right that if I choose a sift down as a constant time operation, I have the right recurrence. I just find it hard to justify this in my notes where I would need to show the operation as well, and where this is very clearly *not* a constant time operation. I just don't think I can justify calling it constant time. I cannot hide this if I include an implementation of the opration.